# ggarrange always covers bottom right x-axis with axis title

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

So I've been trying to stitch a set of four plots together and the bottom right x-axis always gets covered with axis title. Originally I thought it might have been because the bottom right plot had a slightly larger y-axis but it doesn't matter which graph I stick in the bottom right corner it always gets covered up....

Here is my code:

```
tiff('Predictors.tiff', units = "in", width = 12, height = 12, res = 1200)
ggarrange(PC5,PN5,HW5,CN5, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
annotate_figure(figure,top = text_grob("Predictors of N Mineralization", size = 20),
            left = text_grob("N mineralization after 6 months (mg/kg)", size = 20, rot = 90))

dev.off()
```

PC5,PN5 etc. are all names of plots

[image: picture of four plots with bottom right plot's x-axis numbers covered by x-axis title]

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with the plot? May you share the plot individually and highlight what was deleted when using `ggarrange`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on my machine. It would be helpful if you provide a reproducible example.